# How to create a Google Contact using the new People API and at the same time registered that contact into multiple groups/labels

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-people-api

Google People API - the new version of Google Contacts Api

How can I create a new contact using Google People API and at the same time "register" or add that contact to multiple user groups/labels. Previously using the google contact api this was trivial but Google has now updated their API and depreciated their OLD API.

I have an example below of what I am trying to achieve. For example I wish to create a new contact "Steve Jobs" that belongs to the groups/labels in google contacts "Apple" and "Technology" and "Super_User".

I am using this endpoint - https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact

Also you should note that it works fine with 1 group but not with multiple groups.

Thank you in advance!

````
 "memberships": [
   {
     "contactGroupMembership": {
       "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/123456789010",
       "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/1234567890"
     }
   }
 ]
}
   }
 ],
 "names": [
   {
     "familyName": "Jobs",
     "givenName": "Steve"
   }
 ]
}```
````

Comment: Have you tried chaining them with a comma? `"contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/123456789010, contactGroups/1234567890"`?

Comment: Hi Rafa yes I have
it returns invalid argument 

 {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Contact group resource name \"contactGroups/123456789, contactGroups/12345556789\" must be in the format \"contactGroups/\u003ccontact_group_id\u003e\".",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}

Comment: ]Curious - have you tried retrieving a contact that is already a member of multiple grous using the API and seeing how the response is structured?

Comment: Rafa - thats actually a really awesome idea, wish I had thought about that earlier. I solved it long time ago. The solution is below. Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself. I'm a silly person. Obviously you need to ensure that the contact group id equals an existing ID that is in your Google Contacts account. You can see the ID by creating a group in google contacts then clicking on the group name. Look in your URL and it will show the contact group ID.

```
 "memberships": [
    {
      "contactGroupMembership": {
        "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/123456789"
      }
    },
    {
      "contactGroupMembership": {
        "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/123456789832"
      }
    },
    {
      "contactGroupMembership": {
        "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/232353433233"
      }
    }
  ]
```